# Validate salary input jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to validate input value must be like 1.400,00 and 12.000,00.
If input has the correct value, it should remove the disabled class from the else stays disabled.

I tried like this but did't get success :(

```
<input id="ex2" class="salary" type="number" placeholder="1.400,00 - 12.000,00" name="salaryRange2"/>

<a href="#" id="checkSalary1" class="btn next disabled">Next Step</a>

$("#ex2").on("keyup", function(){
    var valid = /^\d{1,6}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(this.value),
        val = this.value;

    if(valid){
        console.log("Invalid input!");
        this.value = val.substring(0, val.length - 1);
        $("#checkSalary1").removeClass("disabled");
    }
    else{
        $("#checkSalary1").addClass("disabled");
    }
});
```

Can anyone help how can achieve this condition?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your regex looks nothing like your requirement. It looks for 1-6 numbers followed by a `.` followed by 0-2 further digits. And there is another step - once it looks like a valid number, you need to parse it to a number and check its in the valid range - harder to do with regex alone.

Comment: Put your regex into https://regex101.com/ and read what it does and add some of your values will see it doesn't come close

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is way out, something like this gets you a little closer:

> ^\d{1,2}.\d{3},\d{2}$

Which looks for:

- 1-2 digits
- a literal `.`
- 3 digits
- a literal `,`
- 2 digits

You may like to enhance this to make the decimal portion optional.

From there, you need to actually parse the string to a number to check it is within the valid numerical range (as, for example `95.000,00` would pass on a regex check, but not in the range check.

Answer (score 0):

The number input value is a ... `Number`, so you can just use a numeric comparison, no `RegExp` needed. Furthermore, the `keyup` event will not trigger if you use a mouse to increment or decrement its value.

Here's a snippet that continuously checks the salary input value, enables or disables the button as applicable and shows a message about the input value validity. To make your live even easier, for a `[type=number]`-input you can also set a minimum and maximum value by the way (used in the snippets `checkValue` method).

[**See also**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/mruyzafv/embedded/result,js,html,css)

```js
(() => {
  const inputElement = document.querySelector("#ex2");
  const report = document.querySelector("#report");
  const bttn = document.querySelector("button");
  const getAction = cando => cando ? "removeAttribute" : "setAttribute";
  const checkVal = val => val
      && val >= +inputElement.getAttribute("min")  
      && val <= +inputElement.getAttribute("max");
  const messages = {
    cando: "Ok to submit",
    noValue: "Waiting for input (1.400,00 - 12.000,00)",
    invalid: "Value should be from 1.400,00 up to 12.000,00"
  };
  
  inputElement.focus();
  checkValue();

  function checkValue() {
    const val = inputElement.value;
    const cando = checkVal(val);
    report.innerHTML = !val 
      ? messages.noValue
      : cando
        ? messages.cando
        : messages.invalid;
    bttn[getAction(cando)]("disabled", true);
    return setTimeout(checkValue, 200);
  }
})();
```

```html
<input id="ex2" 
  class="salary" 
  type="number"
  min="1400" 
  max="12000"
  step="0.01"
  name="salaryRange2"/>

<button disabled>submit</button> <span id="report"></span>
```