# Regex to validate a number while typing

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate a number, while user starts typing in the input field. I tried with the following regular expression it's not working fully.

```
/^\d+(?:\.\d{1,3})?$/
```

It's satisfied following cases as I expected.
`120` ---> True,
`120.2` ---> True,
`120.123` --> True
`120g` --> False

It's not satisfying a single case as I expected.

`120.` --> returning false --> But I am expecting true.

can anyone help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the digits following the possible `.` to be optional, in case the user just typed the period but hasn't typed further yet. Use `\d{0,3}` rather than `\d{1,3}`:

```js
console.log(/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,3})?$/.test('120.'));
```

If you want to verify that there's no trailing period, do so *after the user indicates that they're done typing*, such as on form submit, in which case you can use your original regex.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time it's a bad idea to use `RegExp` for validation of number values. Use `<input type="number">`. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51785481/validate-salary-input-jquery/51785898#51785898) for validation, the snippet from that answer:

```js
(() => {
  const inputElement = document.querySelector("#ex2");
  const report = document.querySelector("#report");
  const bttn = document.querySelector("button");
  const getAction = cando => cando ? "removeAttribute" : "setAttribute";
  const checkVal = val => val
      && val >= +inputElement.getAttribute("min")  
      && val <= +inputElement.getAttribute("max");
  const messages = {
    cando: "Ok to submit",
    noValue: "Waiting for input (1.400,00 - 12.000,00)",
    invalid: "Value should be from 1.400,00 up to 12.000,00"
  };
  
  inputElement.focus();
  checkValue();

  function checkValue() {
    const val = inputElement.value;
    const cando = checkVal(val);
    report.innerHTML = !val 
      ? messages.noValue
      : cando
        ? messages.cando
        : messages.invalid;
    bttn[getAction(cando)]("disabled", true);
    return setTimeout(checkValue, 200);
  }
})();
```

```html
<input id="ex2" 
  type="number"
  min="1400" 
  max="12000"
  step="0.01"/>

<button disabled>submit</button> <span id="report"></span>
```